# Tornado doesn't seem to extract properly the + (plus) sign from from the request URL

Tags: python, tornado

For my python app, I'm using tornado 6.0.4 framework. Lately I've noticed that for some reasons, torando is not able to extract properly the query parameters, which contain the + sign.

This is a preview of my request structure, in my handler:

```
path:'/namespaces/2/environments/'
protocol:'http'
query:'limit=10&offset=0&sort=+id'
query_arguments:{'limit': [b'10'], 'offset': [b'0'], 'sort': [b' id']}
remote_ip:'172.21.0.12'
server_connection:<tornado.http1connection.HTTP1ServerConnection object at 0x7f8328068820>
uri:'/namespaces/2/environments/?limit=10&offset=0&sort=+id'
version:'HTTP/1.1'
_body_future:None
_cookies:<SimpleCookie: >
_finish_time:None
'limit':[b'10']
'offset':[b'0']
'sort':[b' id']
__len__:3
```

you can see that the sort query param contains a +, but for some reasons the query parameters structure generated by tornado, replaces the + with an empty space.

If I try to encode that + char at the source I get something like this:

```
query:'limit=10&offset=0&sort=%252Bid'
query_arguments:{'limit': [b'10'], 'offset': [b'0'], 'sort': [b',%2Bid']}
remote_ip:'172.21.0.12'
'limit':[b'10']
'offset':[b'0']
'sort':[b'%2Bid']
```

So the param in the URL gets encoded twice and decoded once in the query params structure.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: How are you encoding the plus sign at the source? I think the problem is whatever is causing that double encoding, but that's happening on the client side and not in Tornado.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘+’ is a space character in a query, which I doubt should be there. But + is the correct representation in the query and space is the correct representation in a decoded query parameter value, so there may be nothing wrong.